# Add preview text of email via mandrill

Tags: c#, mandrill

As I am using mandrill dll (1.0.75) for sending mail in my project. In mobile view there is showing some text in inbox in preview text(which is not giving by me).
I want to customise text in preview text in email via C# code.As I looked all fields of mandrill dll but I am not able to found relevant text for preview text. Is there any updated dll so we can get field for preview text?

May I request to please suggest, How to add preview text in email via C# code (which will show with subject in inbox.)?

Thanks in advance...